# No executable file created

Tags: bash, gcc

Why isn't the newly named executable file being created? But if I delete the `shift`, it does create the file?

```bash
if [ "$1" = "-o" ]; 
then
  op="$2"
  shift 2
  gcc -o "$op" "$@" &> errors.txt
else
 shift
 echo "went to else -o not detected"
 gcc "$@" &> errors.txt
fi
```

Comment: If you add the line `set -x` before your code, bash will print the exact line with variables expanded before running it.

Comment: Are you passing `-o` to the script?

Comment: the current input for this script is ./compile -o executable_filename file1 file2 file3 ....op should be the executable_filename

Comment: I want to gcc ONLY file1 file2 file3 ... which are the rest of the arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `-o` to the script then the script will pass `-o` to `gcc` and therefore call the resultant file something *other* than "a.out". Because that's what passing `-o` to `gcc` does.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to do. Change the a.out file's name. But upon ls the newly created executable file is not there.

Comment: Then not only did you not read your script, but you also didn't even read your question.

Comment: Yes. And given the command line you wrote in your comment it would be called "executable_filename", not "a.out".

Comment: Yes, but executable_filename doesn't exist after running this

Comment: Have you tried not throwing out all error messages?

Comment: Yes I have still nothing

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for your help!